# How to solve W1047/W1068 warnings when assigning char to string?

Tags: string, delphi, char, compiler-warnings, delphi-xe7

I have a simple function that converts a number to a string (similar to how Excel column numbers `1..n` can be converted into column names `A-ZZZ`). As I use this a lot, I have removed local variables as a speed optimization and only work with the `Result` directly.

When I compile, I get these 2 warnings:

> W1047 Unsafe code 'String index to var param'

> W1068 Modifying strings in place may not be supported in the future

Here is the shortened function:

```
function Idx2Code_(Idx: integer): string;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 3); // init Result size
  if Idx <= 26 then
  begin
    // single char: A-Z
    Result := Chr(64 + Idx);
    SetLength(Result, 1);
  end
  else if Idx <= 676 then
  begin
    // 2 chars codes: BA-ZZ
    Result[1] := Chr((Idx div 26) + 64 + 1); // <- warnings for this line
    Result[2] := Chr((Idx mod 26) + 64);     // <- warnings for this line
    SetLength(Result, 2);
  end
  else
  begin
    // 3 chars codes: BAA-ZZZ
    Result[1] := Chr((Idx div 676) + 64 + 1);            // <- warnings for this line
    Result[2] := Chr(((Idx mod 676) div 26) + 64 + 26);  // <- warnings for this line
    Result[3] := Chr((Idx mod 26) + 64 + 26);            // <- warnings for this line
  end;
end;
```

I can use local variables, but its slower, which I do not want.

I don't want to use code that might become "obsolete" in a future Delphi version.

**How can I solve the warnings, but keep the simplicity and speed as much as possible?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In mobile development, direct indexing of Delphi's `string` type is **0-based** by default (this can be disabled with the [`{$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS OFF}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Zero-based_strings_(Delphi)) directive).

In desktop development, direct indexing is still **1-based** by default, but *may* become 0-based in the future.

Because of this discrepancy between platforms, direct indexing of `string` is discouraged moving forward, thus the warning messages.  To avoid this, there is a 0-based [`TStringHelper.Chars[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Chars) property available on all platforms.  However, this property is **read-only**, so you cannot use it to modify the content of a `string` (at one point, Embarcadero was considering making `string` immutable, but then later decided against it, but the warning remains).

In this situation, you will have to either:

1. disable the warnings, and use platform-appropriate indexing.  You can use `Low(string)` to help you with that:

   ```
   {$WARN UNSAFE_CODE OFF}
   {$WARN IMMUTABLE_STRINGS OFF}
   function Idx2Code_(Idx: integer): string;
   begin
     if Idx <= 26 then
     begin
       // single char: A-Z
       SetLength(Result, 1);
       Result[Low(string)] := Chr(64 + Idx);
     end
     else if Idx <= 676 then
     begin
       // 2 chars codes: BA-ZZ
       SetLength(Result, 2);
       Result[Low(string)] := Chr((Idx div 26) + 64 + 1);
       Result[Low(string)+1] := Chr((Idx mod 26) + 64);
     end
     else
     begin
       // 3 chars codes: BAA-ZZZ
       SetLength(Result, 3);
       Result[Low(string)] := Chr((Idx div 676) + 64 + 1);
       Result[Low(string)+1] := Chr(((Idx mod 676) div 26) + 64 + 26);
       Result[Low(string)+2] := Chr((Idx mod 26) + 64 + 26);
     end;
   end;
   {$WARN IMMUTABLE_STRINGS DEFAULT}
   {$WARN UNSAFE_CODE DEFAULT}
   ```
2. use a [`TStringBuilder`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringBuilder):

   ```
   uses
     System.SysUtils;

   function Idx2Code_(Idx: integer): string;
   var
     SB: TStringBuilder;
   begin
     SB := TStringBuilder.Create(3);
     try
       if Idx <= 26 then
       begin
         // single char: A-Z
         SB.Append(Chr(64 + Idx));
       end
       else if Idx <= 676 then
       begin
         // 2 chars codes: BA-ZZ
         SB.Append(Chr((Idx div 26) + 64 + 1));
         SB.Append(Chr((Idx mod 26) + 64));
       end
       else
       begin
         // 3 chars codes: BAA-ZZZ
         SB.Append(Chr((Idx div 676) + 64 + 1));
         SB.Append(Chr(((Idx mod 676) div 26) + 64 + 26));
         SB.Append(Chr((Idx mod 26) + 64 + 26));
       end;
       Result := SB.ToString;
     finally
       SB.Free;
     end;
   end;
   ```

   Alternatively, `TStringbuilder` does have its own [`Chars[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringBuilder.Chars) property that is writable:

   ```
   uses
     System.SysUtils;

   function Idx2Code_(Idx: integer): string;
   var
     SB: TStringBuilder;
   begin
     SB := TStringBuilder.Create(3);
     try
       if Idx <= 26 then
       begin
         // single char: A-Z
         SB.Length := 1;
         SB[0] := Chr(64 + Idx);
       end
       else if Idx <= 676 then
       begin
         // 2 chars codes: BA-ZZ
         SB.Length := 2;
         SB[0] := Chr((Idx div 26) + 64 + 1);
         SB[1] := Chr((Idx mod 26) + 64);
       end
       else
       begin
         // 3 chars codes: BAA-ZZZ
         SB.Length := 3;
         SB[0] := Chr((Idx div 676) + 64 + 1);
         SB[1] := Chr(((Idx mod 676) div 26) + 64 + 26);
         SB[2] := Chr((Idx mod 26) + 64 + 26);
       end;
       Result := SB.ToString;
     finally
       SB.Free;
     end;
   end;
   ```

See Embarcadero's documentation for more information:

[Migrating Delphi Code to Mobile from Desktop](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop): [Use 0-Based Strings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop#Use_0-Based_Strings)

Comment: It says `E2129 Cannot assign to read-only property` on line `Result.Chars[0]:= Chr(64 + Idx);'. I do have SystemSysutils used. What am I missing here?

Comment: My bad, I forgot that `TStringHelper.Chars[]` is indeed read-only, you can't use it to modify the content of a `string`. I will update my answer.

Comment: @MikeTorrettinni, use [StringBuilder](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringBuilder.Chars)

Comment: @LURD: yes, `TStringBuilder` is one option, but Mike seems to be focused on performance, so the added overhead of allocating the `TStringBuilder` itself and making method calls to append data to it may not be to Mike's liking.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I fully agree. But the alternative to always have to use Low()/High() is so ugly. Seems Emba did their best to confuse the Delphi community.

Comment: Great, thank you for all the options! Will benchmark with `TStringBuilder` but I assume Low(string) would be faster. Any hints on how to improve question to back to 0 points, so it doesn't get deleted? I'm sure your deailed answer will be useful for others in similar situation.

Comment: Did some tests and version with `Low(string)` seem to be fastest (in test circumstances). But other are not too slower (up to 5%). Will use `Low` with Warnings switched off.

Comment: If you use Low(string) you don't have to turn of warnings. Turning off warnings is quite tricky. I personally never would, except perhaps platform warnings for a dedicated app.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis using `Low(string)` does not avoid the W1068 warning.

Comment: Why not simply `Result := Chr(...) + Chr(...) + Chr(...)`?